# Access other tables in the same database in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

[image]

We're using two backends languages, JAVA and Python (Django), to handle different modules in the same project.

As shown above, in the database, pl_**** tables work for the JAVA part and qa_**** tables work for my Django part.

Right now, my Django part want to use the pl_user table, what should I do to access the data? Do I need add anything in the models.py? Or, do I need make some relationships between pl_user table and auth_user table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need to define models, which `inspectdb` can do for you automatically. You will need to mark them as `managed = False` so that migrations won't be generated for them.

Comment: here is the informathion about it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/legacy-databases/